# Convert PHP array to Json String

Tags: php, json

Just wondering if it is possible to convert a PHP array to JSON string
Heres the following PHP array:

```
array ( 
     'players' => array ( 
          '123' => '345'
          '567' => '789'
      ), 
     'non_players' => array ( 
          0 => '71558060', 
          1 => '14451395', 
          2 => '16428783', 
          3 => '12070702', 
          4 => '16872249', 
          5 => '10081837', 
          6 => '10000363', 
          7 => '10084478', 
     ), 
)
```

Is it possible to convert to JSON string?

Comment: did you check https://www.google.co.in/search?q=INSERT+IGNORE&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&gfe_rd=cr&ei=6dF9U5eZN4We_waRvIHgCw#channel=fs&q=php+array+to+json

Comment: Yes there is, it is called [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Please don't think before posting to SO. :)

Comment: People should have more reputation to ask questions... it would eliminate a lot of these trivial and ill-researched questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `json_encode()`, from the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Wont that just turn it into a JSON array?

Comment: JSON in PHP is just a String (special formatted string). So it will convert the PHP array into a valid JSON string.